# Exporting a Backup of All Orders

Tags: export, importexport, backup

We are currently making a major overhaul to an old website of ours, and it is still using Magento Version 1.4.1.1. I know it is very outdated.

We have a lot of orders here that we want to make a backup of, such as name, email address, telephone order, sale amount, date of order(s), items ordered, etc.

There are over 10k transactions.

How do I easily back it up in a reader friendly format, preferably on a spreadsheet?

I have seen plugins like https://marketplace.magento.com/raveinfosys-raveinfosys-orderexporter.html but it only goes until version 1.5.

I have a little programming knowledge, but prefer an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

DIR . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$orderData = getOrderCollection();
echo '

```
';print_r($orderData);die;
function getOrderCollection()
{
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
    //echo '';print_r($order->getData());die;
    foreach($order as $_order)
    {
        $orderData[$_order->getId()]['customer_Firstname'] = $_order->getData('customer_firstname');
        $orderData[$_order->getId()]['customer_Lastname'] = $_order->getData('customer_lastname');
        $orderData[$_order->getId()]['customer_Email'] = $_order->getData('customer_email');
        $orderItems = $_order->getAllItems();
        foreach($orderItems as $item)
        {
            //echo '';print_r($item->getData());die;
            $orderData[$_order->getId()][$item->getId()]['item_name'] = $item->getName();
        }
```

`}


return $orderData;`

}

Comment: Hi! This code is for Magento 2 and he's asking for Magento 1.

Answer (score -1):

The export option in sales grid isn't what you are looking for?
You can install an extension like this one to export orders to csv: https://amasty.com/efficient-order-export.html#m1

Regards,

Pablo

Comment: -1? Really? Why? He needs to export orders from Magento 1.4 and this module (Amasty) is compatible with 1.4.